# Funcion no me entrega el resultado esperado

Tags: javascript, nodejs

este post será totalmente en cuanto a lógica.
Dejare un link con los 2 arrays que estoy utilizando por si alguien quiere intentar hacerlo en sus maquinas

[CodeShare](https://codeshare.io/5zOjDW)

Les cuento.

Tengo 2 arrays con cierta estructura, mi idea es que en el array de NOTAS busque cual objeto tiene la propiedad notas y la inserte dentro del array principal tomando en consideración

1.- El "elemento" sea el mismo

2.- El "uso" sea el mismo

3.- La "fecha" sea el mismo

Entonces como pueden observar en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El objeto de la izquierda coincide con el objeto de las derechas, asi que quiero TOMAR las notas asociadas e insertarlas en el array principal que tenga esos campos

Mi codigo:

```
const addNotesToMain = (notesPrincipal, notes) => {
    const notesMapped = notes.reduce((acc, note) => {
        const { propiedades } = note
        propiedades.forEach(propiedad => {
            const { frecuenciaUso } = propiedad
            frecuenciaUso.forEach(frecuencia => {
                if (frecuencia.hasOwnProperty('notas')) {
                    const obj = {
                        elemento: note.elemento,
                        uso: propiedad.uso,
                        fecha: frecuencia.fecha,
                        notas: frecuencia.notas
                    }
                    acc[note.elemento] = obj
                }
            })
        })
        return acc
    }, {})

    const mergedMain = notesPrincipal.map(principal => {
        const { elemento, propiedades } = principal
        if (notesMapped.hasOwnProperty(elemento)) {
            propiedades.forEach(propiedad => {
                if (notesMapped[elemento].uso === propiedad.uso) {
                    const { frecuenciaUso } = propiedad
                    frecuenciaUso.forEach(frecuencia => {
                        if (notesMapped[elemento].fecha === frecuencia.fecha) {
                            frecuencia = { ...frecuencia, notas: notesMapped[elemento].notas }
                            return frecuencia
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
        return principal
    })
}

addNotesToMain(arrPrincipal, arrNotes)
```

**NotesMapped** lo que hace es generar un objeto con la información que necesito, es decir, algo asi

```
{
  carro: {
    elemento: 'carro',
    uso: 'personal',
    fecha: '2021-09-21',
    notas: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  bus: {
    elemento: 'bus',
    uso: 'publico',
    fecha: '2021-09-22',
    notas: [ [Object] ]
  }
}
```

**MergedMain** finalmente lo que esta haciendo es validando si el campo que esta iterando en el momento cumple con los requisitos que mencioné anteriormente. En lo más dentro de los bucles estoy actualizando mi campo **frecuencia** para que en vez de estar

```
{ fecha: '2021-09-21' }
```

Mute y se transforme en esto

```
{
  fecha: '2021-09-21',
  notas: [
    { km: '1000', conductor: 'pepito' },
    { km: '900', conductor: 'antonia' }
  ]
}
```

**Problema**

No me esta tomando el "return frecuencia" ubicado en el corazon del mergedMain, puse un console log de frecuencia editado y SI esta como necesito que este, el tema es justamente ese, no me esta reemplazando el valor.

Asi que si alguien puede echarme una mano con eso, agradecido a mil

pd:Se que en temas de timeComplexity el algoritmo es un asco por la cantidad de iteraciones, pero asi está planteado y solo me falta ese pequeño detalle que les comento

Muchas gracias!